# Spring security evitar manipulación de URL

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy usando Spring Security para manejar los permisos de ciertas vistas con la anotacion `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`. En parte esto me funciona porque los usuario normales no pueden ingresar a una cierta URL por ejemplo:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/usuarios/detalle/1
```

Como "ROLE_USER" solo puedo ver hasta: http://localhost:8080/app/usuarios

Como "ROLE_ADMIN" puedo ver hasta: http://localhost:8080/app/usuarios/detalle/1

en donde `/detalle/1` es una vista que recibe como parametro el id del usuarios seleccionado.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@GetMapping(value = "/detalle/{id}")
public String detalle(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id, Map<String,Object>model, RedirectAttributes flash) {

  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  Usuario usuario_logeado = usuarioService.getUsuario(auth.getName());

  Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findById(id);
  if (usuario == null) {
    flash.addFlashAttribute("error", "No existe el usuario");
    return "redirect:/usuarios";
  }
  model.put("usuario_logeado", usuario_logeado.getNombre());
  model.put("usuario", usuario);
  return "usuarios/detalle";
}
```

Como veran al inicio me trae una tabla de usuarios que son de mi area y como administrador puedo ir al detalle de cada uno.

Como son varios administradores y cada administrador maneja un área con sus respectivos colaboradores, entonces como administrador solo puedo ver a ciertos usuarios que están en mi área, mas no a todos, ya que manipulando el `/1` puedo cambiar de valor y ver el detalle de otros usuario que no me corresponden.

Como arreglaría ese problema, he visto algunas web donde el id viene con un token largo de caracteres, o tal vez no.

Comment: Comprueba si ese id permite a ese administrador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un atributo en tu entity `Usuario` con nombre `adminPropietario` donde guardes a que administrador le pertenece. Con una consulta jpa puedes hacer algo asi (Tu CRUD repository o tu DAO, como trabajes con el):

```
public Usuario findUsuarioByIdByAmdinPropietario(int id, String propietario);
```

En tu service lo implementas así:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)  
public findById(int id, String propietario){
    return interfaceUsuarioDao.findUsuarioByIdByAmdinPropietario(id, propietario).orElse(null);
};
```

Después en tu controller válidas que no sea `null`, de otra manera significa que el `Admin` está tratando de acceder a un `usuario` que no le toca.

El `usuario_logueado` ya lo estás obteniendo entonces ya no hay problema con eso.

> **Puede que el código no funcione por que lo escribi directamente.**

Comment: viendo tu ejemplo use un método que busca por id e id_manager, gracias.